# Calculating dot product on very big matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

how to approach calculating dot product for M1 shape 5e7x50 and M2 shape 50x5e7? Also dividing one matrix 5e7x5e7 by another matrix of the same size?

Is subseting the way to go?

Comment: Do you have ~ 10/20TB to store this resulting-matrix? I think you are missing something critical here. This does not look very feasible in time- and space. If it is what you really want to do: google out-of-core or distributed matrix-multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tensorflow with GPU:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.matmul(np.array(....), np.array(....))
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `numpy`:

```
np.dot(mat_a, mat_b)
```

if by division you mean element-wise division than you can also use:

```
np.divide(x1, x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@` operator in numpy.

```
import numpy as np

np.array(...) @ np.array(...)
```